# How do I update an object in a deeply nested array of objects with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update the value of an object in a deeply nested array in mongoose, but havn't been able to come up with the correct syntax.

I have tried both atomic updates and the conventional way of updating items in mongodb still with no luck.

**I want to update 'history[index].rideConfirmations[index].rideComplete.driverConfirmed**

```
//driverHistorySchema.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const DriversRideHistorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    driverId: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    driverName: String,
    history: [
      {
        date: String,
        rideConfirmations: [
          {
            riderConfirmationTime: String,
            driverConfirmationTime: String,
            riderName: String,
            riderId: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            rideComplete: {
              riderConfirmed: Boolean,
              driverConfirmed: Boolean,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true, collection: "driversRideHistory" }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("DriversRideHistory", DriversRideHistorySchema);
```

**I want to update 'history[index].rideConfirmations[index].rideComplete.driverConfirmed**

```
router.put("/rideHistory/completeRide", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { driverId, dateIndex, riderIndex } = req.body;

    await DriversHistoryModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        driverId: driverId,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "history.$[dateIndex].rideConfirmations.$[riderIndex].rideComplete.driverConfirmed": true,
        },
      },
      { arrayFilters: [{ dateIndex: dateIndex }, { riderIndex: riderIndex }] }
    );

    return res.status(200).send("Ride Completed Successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send("An error occured while processing this request");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.put("/rideHistory/completeRide", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const { driverId, dateIndex, riderIndex } = req.body;
    //Update history on driver's profile first
    const driver = await DriversHistoryModel.findOne({
      driverId,
    });

    const dateToUpdate =
      driver.history[dateIndex].rideConfirmations[riderIndex];

    dateToUpdate.rideComplete.driverConfirmed = true;

    await driver.save();

    return res.status(200).send(dateToUpdate);


    return res.status(200).send("Ride Completed Successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send("An error occured while processing this request");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the value of an object in a deeply nested array in Mongoose, you can use the positional $ operator combined with the dot notation. Here's a basic example:

```
DriverHistoryModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "nestedArray._id": objectIdOfParentDocument, "nestedArray.nestedArray2._id": objectIdOfNestedDocument },
      { $set: { "nestedArray.$.nestedArray2.$[elem].propertyName": newValue } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": objectIdOfDesiredElement }] },
      function(err, doc) {
        // Handle error or updated document
      }
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you are using the `$set` operator along with the `arrayFilters` option, which is the right approach. However, you have to make sure that the variables `dateIndex` and `riderIndex` are defined and have the correct values.

Here's an adjusted version of your code:

```
router.put("/rideHistory/completeRide", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { driverId, dateIndex, riderIndex } = req.body;
    if (dateIndex === undefined || riderIndex === undefined) {
      return res.status(400).send("Invalid dateIndex or riderIndex");
    }

    await DriversHistoryModel.findOneAndUpdate({ driverId: driverId },
      {
        $set: {
          [`history.${dateIndex}.rideConfirmations.${riderIndex}.rideComplete.driverConfirmed`]: true,
        },
      }
    );

    return res.status(200).send("Ride Completed Successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(404).send("An error occurred while processing this request");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

In this adjusted version:
The `dateIndex` and `riderIndex` are used directly in the `$set` operator with template literals to dynamically construct the path to the nested field.